# How do I get the user-name in every thread (Laravel)?

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel

I wan't to get the name of the user who created is own thread. Like Michael did a thread about food. So at the bottom of the food-thread should be the name of Michael.

I've wrote the code for this but it doesn't really works. Maybe someone of you can find the mistake.

I have two models. A thread Model and a users model.

thread model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models\Thread;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class Thread extends Model {
    public $table = 'thread';
    public $fillable = [
        'thread',
        'content',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function userthread() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User','user_id', 'id');
```

user model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

   use ...

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function threaduser() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Thread\Thread','user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

and now the controller method, where I'm trying to get the name:

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        $thread = Thread::query()->findOrFail($id);
        $threaduser = Thread::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->with('userthread')->get();
        return view('test.show', [
            'thread' => $thread,
            'threaduser' => $threaduser
        ]);
    }
```

in my html:

```
{{$threaduser->name}}
```

The error message I get is :

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name (View: /var/www/laravel/logs/resources/views/test/show.blade.php)

I hope someone can help me there.

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
{{$threaduser->userthread->name}}
```

change userthread() function in your Thread Class to

```
public function userthread() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: I did but now I'm getting this Error Message: Class 'User' not found

Comment: I did, but now I'm getting the same error like before: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$userthread ( in my html )

Comment: You need to iterate through your collection if you use get(). So build foreach loop to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`get()` gives you a Collection not a Model you either have to do a foreach on it like

```
@foreach ($threadusers as $threaduser)
    {{ $threaduser->userthread->name }}
@endforeach
```

Or use `first` instead of `get` if there is only one Thread per User.

Depending on what you want to do, of course.

Comment: I did that but now it give's me just every user I have in my database under the thread :/

Comment: You did what exactly?

Comment: I used the foreach loop you gave me there. And now I'm just getting every user in the thread written

Comment: But what do you want. How do you want your response to be

Comment: So you're telling me that `$threadusers` is a collection of user or did I miss something?